# Python3: dealing with sqlite3 SELECT using variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I trying to get an SQL selection with the `LIKE` parameter, but it gives my only:

```
false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: Message text is empty"
```

Here is my code:

```
textvar = message.text 
c.execute("SELECT * FROM run WHERE act LIKE '+textvar+'")
res = c.fetchone() 
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, res)
```

`print textvar` gives me an expected `sting`, taken from `message.text`. I've tried to get some data without `LIKE` and that seems everything else works pretty well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing if the string `'+textvar+'` (**not** the value from the variable `textvar`!) is present in your `act` column. There are no such columns.

Don't use string interpolation to insert variables into SQL queries, because that opens you wide to SQL injection attacks. Use query parameters:

```
textvar = '%{}%'.format(message.text)
c.execute("SELECT * FROM run WHERE act LIKE ?", (textvar,))
```

Note that I do use string interpolation to add `%` *wildcards* to the string to make sure `LIKE` searches for text *anywhere in the column*. Without wildcards `LIKE` is nothing more than an equality test. `%` matches 0 or more arbitrary characters, `_` matches exactly 1 arbitrary character. See the [`LIKE` operator documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).

So, for your sample text `'sting'`, the above code produces the string `'%sting%'`, and then the database adapter takes care of proper quoting and executes a `SELECT * FROM run WHERE act LIKE '%sting%'` SQL query against your database. Any row where the `act` column *contains* the substring `sting` will match and be returned.

Comment: thanks for an answer, it was just my inattention (i was thought that there were a matches), thank for editing my question as well.